# Javascript transform flat data to nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, reduce

I am pretty new to react/ES6 and I got a strange behavior when I use reduce method to transform a flat array I receive from an API into a nested object.
I was aleready familiar with map and filter but never used reduce before.

I am pretty sure that I am using it wrong but it goes like this.

I have the folowing flat dataset:

```
[
  {
    category:"Category1",
    subCategory:"SubCategory1",
    productType:"ProductType1",
    brand:"brand1"
  },
  {
    category:"Category1",
    subCategory:"SubCategory2",
    productType:"ProductType2",
    brand:"brand2"
  },
  {
    category:"Category1",
    subCategory:"SubCategory2",
    productType:"ProductType2",
    brand:"brand3"
  },
  {
    category:"Category2",
    subCategory:"SubCategory1",
    productType:"ProductType1",
    brand:"brand1"
  },
  {
    category:"Category2",
    subCategory:"SubCategory1",
    productType:"ProductType2",
    brand:"brand2"
  }
]
```

I am using the folowing code to get a nested object from the flat dataset.

```
getNestedData() {
  var baseData = this.getBaseData();

  return baseData.reduce((categories,category) => {
    if(!categories[category.category]){
      categories[category.category] = {
        category: category.category,
        subCategories: baseData.filter(bd => bd.category === category.category)
          .reduce((subCategories,subCategory) => {
            if(!subCategories[subCategory.subCategory]) {
              subCategories[subCategory.subCategory] = {
                subCategory: subCategory.subCategory,
                productTypes: baseData.filter(bd => bd.category === subCategory.category && bd.subCategory === subCategory.subCategory)
                  .reduce((productTypes,productType) => {
                    if(!productTypes[productType.productType]) {
                      productTypes[productType.productType] = {
                        productType: productType.productType,
                        brands: baseData.filter(bd => bd.category === productType.category && bd.subCategory === productType.subCategory && bd.productType === productType.productType)
                          .reduce((brands,brand) => {
                            if(!brands[brand.brand]) {
                              brands[brand.brand] = {
                                brand: brand.brand
                              }
                            }
                            return brands;
                          }) 
                      };
                    }
                    return productTypes;
                  })
              };
            }
            return subCategories;
          })
      }
    }
    return categories;
  });
}
```

However, the result isn't what I expected. It returns the root array object inside the first category of the array. Like `Category1 => [Category1,Category2]`. And if you go under the category1 child the same thing happen.

I prepared the following [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/252708/) to show my issue.

Let me know what I am doing wrong I googled this for hours. I would also like to know if this way is the most efficient one?

Edit:

There is an example of the expected output:

```
[
  {
    category: "Category1"
    subCategories:[
      {
        subCategory:"SubCategory1",
        productTypes:[
          {
            productType:"ProductType1",
            brands:["Brand1"]    
          }
        ]   
      },
      {
        subCategory:"SubCategory2",
        productTypes:[
          {
            productType:"ProductType2",
            brands:["Brand2","Brand3"]
          }   
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    category: "Category2",
    subCategories:[
      {
        subCategory:"SubCategory1",
        productTypes:[
          {
            productType:"ProductType1",
            brands:["Brand1"]
          },
          {
            productType:"ProductType2",
            brands:["Brand2"]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

### Edit

Mat was right I forgot to pass the initial value when I was using reduce. Passing the initial value made reduce work as I expected. I have then been able to change my code to get the expected result. The code isn't the most elegant but works very well:

```
getNestedData()
{
    var baseData = this.getBaseData();
  return baseData
  .map(c => {return c.category;})
  .reduce((categories,category) => {
  var currentCategory = categories.filter(
    c => c.category === category
  );
    if (currentCategory.length === 0) {
            var categoryData = baseData.filter(bd => bd.category === category);
      categories.push({
        category:category,
        subCategories: categoryData
        .map(c => {return c.subCategory})
        .reduce((subCategories,subCategory) => {
            var currentSubCategory = subCategories.filter(sc => sc.subCategory === subCategory)
            if(currentSubCategory.length === 0)
          {
            var subCategoryData = categoryData.filter(cd => cd.subCategory === subCategory);
            subCategories.push({
                subCategory:subCategory,
              productTypes: subCategoryData
              .map(scd => {return scd.productType})
              .reduce((productTypes,productType) => {
                var currentproductType = productTypes.filter(pt => pt.productType === productType);
                if(currentproductType.length === 0)
                {
                    var productTypeData = subCategoryData.filter(scd => scd.productType === productType)
                  productTypes.push({
                    productType:productType,
                    brands: productTypeData
                    .map(ptd => {return ptd.brand})
                    .reduce((brands,brand) => {
                        var currentBrand = brands.filter(b => b.brand === brand);
                      if(currentBrand.length === 0)
                      {
                        brands.push({brand:brand});
                      }
                      return brands;
                    },[])
                  });
                }
                return productTypes;
              },[])
            });
          }
          return subCategories;
        },[])
      });
    }
    return categories;
  },[])
}
```

[There](https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/252964/) is the working jsFiddle with the expected behavior.

Comment: Can you please show an example of the expected output?

Comment: update You question with expected result otherwise it will be nominated as "unclear what asking", learn to explain Your needs correctly

Comment: There t is let me know if this is clear enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like you are trying to denormalise your array data. Your heavily nested function is difficult to read, and I think you could accomplish what you want much more easily if you use lodash's [`set`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#set) function. For example:

```js
const data = [
  {
    category:"Category1",
    subCategory:"SubCategory1",
    productType:"ProductType1",
    brand:"brand1"
  },
  {
    category:"Category1",
    subCategory:"SubCategory2",
    productType:"ProductType2",
    brand:"brand2"
  },
  {
    category:"Category1",
    subCategory:"SubCategory2",
    productType:"ProductType2",
    brand:"brand3"
  },
  {
    category:"Category2",
    subCategory:"SubCategory1",
    productType:"ProductType1",
    brand:"brand1"
  },
  {
    category:"Category2",
    subCategory:"SubCategory1",
    productType:"ProductType2",
    brand:"brand2"
  }
]

const result = data.reduce((output, item) => {
  _.set(output, `${item.category}.subCategories.${item.subCategory}.productTypes.${item.productType}.brands.${item.brand}.brand`, item.brand)
  return output
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The reason why your code wasn't working (ignoring the typos), is that I think you were forgetting to provide an initial value to the `reduce` function. Look at the last optional argument [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Syntax).

Comment: I will try it tomorrow morning. Thanks! I added an expected output to my original post. Does your solution will give me this output?

Comment: There's a button right there that says "Run code snippet". Look for yourself

Comment: No my solution does not give you the output you updated your question with. It was impossible to infer that you wanted sub types to be arrays. This makes the solution more difficult than what I provided.